# CMake unable to link my project - the only object file is deleted

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have a c++ cmake project, which I want to use for unit tests, but CMake is unable to link. I pushed the reproducing project [here](https://github.com/basprins/gmake-not-linking)

gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~23.04) 12.3.0

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.22)

project(unit-tests)

set(PROJECT_ROOT            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
set(SOURCE                  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

set(COMPILER_DIRECTIVES     "$-O0 -g3 -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS           "${COMPILER_DIRECTIVES}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${COMPILER_DIRECTIVES}")

# Overrides
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS   ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE          ON)

# Project headers
set(project_headers
    ${SOURCE}
)

include_directories(
    ${project_headers}
)

# Source files

file(GLOB_RECURSE unit_test_sources CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${SOURCE}/*.c
    ${SOURCE}/*.cpp
    ${SOURCE}/**/*.c
    ${SOURCE}/**/*.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${unit_test_sources})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
```

Then the only source file I currently have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The project file structure

```
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source/CMakeLists.txt
~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source/serial-monitor-tests.cpp
```

When I compile from terminal:

- cd ~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests
- mkdir -p build
- cd build
- cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ../source
- cmake --build . -- -j12 -Oline --no-print-directory

cmake -G runs to completion

```
bp@legion:~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build(master)$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ../source
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build
```

But the cmake --build does not

```
bp@legion:~/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build(master)$ cmake --build . -- -j12 -Oline --no-print-directory
/usr/bin/cmake -P /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build/CMakeFiles/VerifyGlobs.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source -B/home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build/CMakeFiles /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/depend
cd /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/build/CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o
gmake[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o'
/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source O0 -g3 -Wall -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o -c /home/bp/dev/spatiebas/serial-monitor/unit-tests/source/serial-monitor-tests.cpp
c++: warning: O0: linker input file unused because linking not done
c++: error: O0: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/build.make:79: CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:94: all] Error 2
```

I suspect it has everything to do with deleting the object file, but I have no clue why gmake is doing that

```
gmake[2]: *** Deleting file 'CMakeFiles/unit-tests.dir/serial-monitor-tests.cpp.o'
```

I have an identical project which does compile and run, the only difference is that it does not live in a sub folder (unit-tests). It has to be something super stupid, but I just can't find it...

Comment: In the `CMakeLists.txt` `$-O0` is a **typo**: it produces `O0` (without leading dash!) in the compiler options. Remove the extra dollar sign.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.... !